# How do you use an object reference as a while loop condition in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements, terminate

I am new to Java and encountered a program with a 'while' loop that had the condition being an object reference/call. I traced the code thoroughly and did not see any terminating conditions for the object (it would make sense if the object in the while loop condition had a termination condition that the 'while' loop implementation caused).

NOTE: this involves 'inner'/'nested' classes, so I am not even entirely sure that that is the reason this works. How can a loop be satisfied by this manner of syntax? I will try to frame my question in the pseudocode below:

```
class DemoClass {

    demoClassfoo() {

        InnerClassdemo object2 = this.new InnerDemoClass;

        // Here is where my confusion is. I always thought that the 
        // while loop had to terminate with a logical statement being 
        // satisfied: like it is calling an object? 

        while(object2.innerClassfoo()) { 

            IMPLEMENTATIONS;             
        }                                
    }                                    

    class InnerDemoClass {               

        innerDemoClassfoo() {

            IMPLEMENTATION;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DemoClass object = new DemoClass();

    }
}
```

Comment: It is calling a method that returns a value of type `boolean`.

Comment: The tutorial explains it pretty well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Sotirios, I am ashamed to admit my 'noobness', but I did not actually make that connection that the conditional logic statements that are usually the 'while' condition evaluate to a Boolean True/False value. When I saw a loop, the only thing that comes to my mind is "be sure and count it down, so the loop will terminate!". But, I did not think to just return a Boolean value to do so. This has very much cleared this confusion up. The tutorial was also helpful iamnotmaynard. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 9):

This works since the method `innerClassfoo` returns a `boolean`value, thus satisfying the `while` condition. By the way, the code should look like this:

```
class InnerDemoClass{               

    boolean innerDemoClassfoo(){
        //implementation goes here
        //make sure to ALWAYS return the value
        boolean result = ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how he would NOT return any value in this situation, since its a primitive boolean and not a Boolean? ;-) nevertheless +1